# How do I automatically trim trailing whitespace with Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++, tabs, whitespace

I don't want to delete the empty lines completely, but I want to remove the trailing tabs and whitespaces in them. [Eclipse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29) usually does it (through a preference setting) when we save the file.

For example, the file before saving ($ = end of line):

```
def shuffle(list):$
    import random $
    $
    random.shuffle(list)
    $
$
```

... and when I save this in the editor, Eclipse does the following:

```
def shuffle(list):$
    import random$
$
    random.shuffle(list)
$
$
```

How can I automatically trim trailing whitespace with Notepad++?

Comment: To trim whitespace from multiple files at once, do a Find & Replace for the regular expression `[ \t]+$`. ([Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KI2WA.png)) ([Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9532388/3357935))

Answer (score 107, accepted):

You should be able to do a [regular expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) find/replace in Notepad++ using a pattern like `\s+$`.

There are also a few options under menu *Edit* -> *Blank Operations* that may fit your needs.

Under the "Macro" menu there's an option for "Trim trailing and save". If you need to do a regular expression it may be possible to create a macro however I've never tried them.

Comment: yes in my version of Notepad++, there's an `Edit -> Trim Trailing Space`, but can I trigger that automatically for every save?

Comment: There's an option for "Trim trailing and save" under the Macro menu

Comment: I have bound the Ctrl+S key to the `Macro -> Trim Trailing and save` option, using the `Settings -> Shortcut Mapper...` option.  This is much better than having to remember to run the macro all the time. :)

Comment: Searching `\s+$` will match any empty line, regardless of whitespace. I recommend using `[ \t]+$` instead. (See [How do I remove trailing whitespace using a regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9532388/3357935))

Comment: `^\s+$` should do as well.

Answer (score 91):

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> does what you want. In fact it also saves the file.

**Update**

As 10basetom noted, you can assign a different shortcut to this macro. You can control your shortcuts under *Settings > Shortcut Mapper > [Macros]*.

[image]

Comment: To strip trailing spaces when you save: (1) Remove the default Save shortcut (Ctrl+S), then (2) assign the "Trim Trailing and save" macro to Ctrl+S.

Comment: And to remove the default `Save` shortcut, double click on `Shortcut` field and then select `None` from the combo box.

Comment: I found this page, updated my shortcuts as you suggested and used it happily ever after. Then recently I had to setup a new machine and had completely forgotten how I had done it before... Searched again and found this answer again! You should get +2 for helping me like this!

Comment: Settings > Shortcut Mapper, then tab 'Macros'

Comment: This should be the selected answer for me ^^

Comment: In newer versions you find in the top Menu in `Run`->`Modify Shortcut/Delete command`->tab `Main menu`. Then clear the default `CTRL+S`, and then assign in tab `Macro`  "Trim Trailing and save" to `CTRL+S`

Answer (score 8):

The existing answers look old.

Try below path:

```
Notepad++ > Edit (menu) > Blank Operations > Trim Trailing Space
```

Comment: I recorded a macro to "Trim Trailing Spaces" AND "convert Tabs to Spaces", for consistency in version control. I then Saved the macro with keycode combination `Atl-T`. `Alt-T`, `Ctrl-S` is Quick combo to trim, convert and save.  I purposely do this in two steps, as I do *not* want to trim markdown files, or change tabs/trailing when editing other maintainer's files that may default to a different standard than I use.  `Notepad++ > Edit (menu) > Blank Operations > Trim Trailing Space` and `Notepad++ > Edit (menu) > Blank Operations > TAB to Space`. (N++ also has ... `Space to TAB` options.)

Answer (score 6):

Plugins > Plugin Manager > Show Plugin Manager
Under the Available tab, select EditorConfig and click [Install]

Add an `.editorconfig` file to the folder (name it `.editorconfig.` to avoid Windows error "You must type a filename" - the last dot will be removed)

```
# trims trailing whitespace for all files; filter like [*.{json,xml}]
[*]
trim_trailing_whitespace = true
```

[EditorConfig](http://editorconfig.org/) can also specify encoding, indent and newline character(s), etc.

Comment: Seems that the EditorConfig plugin for Notepad++ does not actually support the trim_trailing_whitespace option: https://github.com/editorconfig/editorconfig-notepad-plus-plus

Comment: Support for `trim_trailing_whitespace` was added on [2016-04-20](https://github.com/editorconfig/editorconfig-notepad-plus-plus/commit/4a0e81cf5d6c903310663adbdf05df7180397869). /cc @jpa

Comment: I wish I could upvote this more, even if only for the `.editorconfig.` trick.  To think that I had been resorting to creating dot-files via the Command Prompt like a caveman for all of these years.

Answer (score 5):

I changed the shortcuts to find a solution to this. I removed the save shortcut (shortcut mapper -> main menu -> save) and mapped <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to the "Trim Trailing and Save" macro (shortcut mapper -> macros -> trim trailing and save). This way the macro replaces the save functionality and there's no need to remember the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> shortcut.

Answer (score 3):

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> is the default shortcut for this. It's in the menu bar as `Macro -> Trim Trailing and save`. You can rebind this under `Settings -> Shortcut Mapper -> [Macros]`.

[image: Rebinding 'Trim Trailing and save' via Shortcut Mapper]

Building on [kon psych's answer](https://superuser.com/a/870221/358766), if you want to automatically trim whitespace any time you save, you can set this to replace the default <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> behavior. Just remember to change or remove the original save shortcut to prevent conflicts.

[image: Disabling the default 'save' shortcut]

Comment: +1 for 'Just remember to change or remove the original save shortcut to prevent conflicts.'

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> -> Switch to tab *Replace* ->

Find what: \t\r

Replace with: \r

Make sure *Extended* search mode is on, then replace all.

If you want to save as well, johanno has the correct solution. Macro -> Trim Trailing and Save works as specified.

Comment: This answer is outdated

Answer (score 1):

In order to preserve the existing menu commands, map (previously unassigned) <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to trim trailing spaces.  Then, do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> together.

This lets you make a small change to a file without confusing text comparison utilities and source control programs by changing (potentially) hundreds of lines.

Comment: Do you know that Shift+Ctrl+T is for reopen recently last closed tabs? This is the same as in modern browsers where you use Ctrl+T to open a new tab. That's why Ctrl+T could be a bit confusing.

Answer (score 1):

These are the precise steps to redirect the standard "Save" shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to do instead "Trim Trailing and Save"

- Settings->Shortcut Mapper...
- Main Menu tab, double click on "Save", change <kbd>S</kbd> to None
- Macros tab, double click on "Trim Trailing Space and Save", change to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>

The Macros shortcut can also be modified from Macro->Modify Shortcut/Delete Macro...

Comment: Thanks, this is absolutely the best answer

Answer (score 0):

Another way -

1. Edit > Blank Operations > Remove Unnecessary Blank and EOL
2. Plugin > XML Tools > Pretty print (XML only - with line breaks)

'XML Tools’ is a plugin that we can install for notepad++

Answer (score 0):

I only wanted to trim non-empty lines. Building off an earlier comment, I searched for `(\S)[ \t]+$` and replaced with `$1`. This leaves blank auto-indented lines unchanged.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).